# Get the data from .txt file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Total number of EVENTS in BOX(planner + ondemand) :  54
EVENT # :1

actualEndTime= '20161121T11:34:00' allowCopyToPlanner= 'True' audioType= '2' audioTypeName= 'Simple stereo' baseType= '3' baseTypeName= 'Download' bookedAsOPPV= 'False' bookingActive= '1' bookingDeletedTime= 'None' bookingDiskQuotaName= 'user' bookingExpirationTime= '19700101T01:00:00' bookingKeep= 'False' bookingLock= 'False' bookingSource= '1' bookingTime= '20161121T11:27:00' bookingType= '4' bookingTypeName= 'Download' boxSetLocator= 'hecid://FFC6AE9C' boxSetName= 'Lost S1' boxSetNameSort= 'Lost S1' boxSetRating= '0' canonicalName= 'Lost' cgmsa= '0' channelID= 'None' channelIDType= 'None' channelName= 'abc studios' channelNr= '102' class= 'object.item.videoItem' cmdcMemberNumber= '1' description= 'A plane crash leaves survivors stranded on a jungle island. Contains violence.(S1, ep 1)' episodeNumber= '1' episodeTitle= 'Pilot (part 1 Of 2) Premiere' estimatedBitRate= '5767168' expireFromPlanner= 'False' extensionStartDur= '0' flagsAllowanalogtaping= 'True' flagsCopyprotected= 'False' flagsCurrentseries= 'False' flagsHasaudiodesc= 'False' flagsHasforeignsubtitles= 'False' flagsHd= 'False' flagsIppv= 'False' flagsIs3D= 'False' flagsIsadult= 'False' flagsIslinked= 'False' flagsOppv= 'False' flagsWidescreen= 'True' genre= '3' genreExtended= '3,772' genreId= 'nds.com_internal' genreName= 'Entertainment' groupID= '0' guardEndDur= 'None' guardStartDur= 'None' isBTO= 'False' isPdlTrailer= '0' isPlaying= 'False' isSeriesLinked= 'False' isShowLinked= '0' isSplitEvent= 'False' isViewed= 'False' itemId= 'BOOK:688045263' itemParentid= '3' itemRestricted= '0' lastPlaybackPosition= '0' lastViewedTime= '19700101T01:00:00' marketingMsg= 'None' oigProgId= '4291238560' parentServiceLocator= 'None' parentalRatingScheme= '1' pdlDownloadStatus= '5' pdlDownloadStatusName= 'ended' pdlPlaybackAvailable= 'True' pdlQueuePosition= '0' pinRating= '4' pinRatingScheme= '1' programID= 'oig://FFC71AA0' programIDType= 'nds.com_URI' purchaseType= '0' pushExpiryEnd= 'None' pushExpiryStart= 'None' pushHasValidTrailer= 'True' pushLocator= 'None' pushPublishTime= 'None' rating= '0' ratingName= 'Unrated' ratingType= 'nds.com_internal' recStatus= '0' recStatusContentstatus= '3' recStatusContentstatusName= 'All' recStatusException= '100' recStatusFailed= 'False' recStatusName= 'Not applicable' recStatusRecstate= '0' recordedDuration= 'P0D00:40:39' recordedStartDateTime= '20161121T11:27:50' recordingID= 'oig://FFC71AA0' reminderStatus= '1' reminderStatusIsvcrtimer= 'False' reminderStatusName= 'event is scheduled for a reminder' remoteCDSItemID= 'None' res= 'file://pvr/2902BCCF' resDuration= '0:40:39' resProtocolinfo= 'internal:10.10.8.89:*:*' resSize= '660887492.0' scheduledDuration= 'P0D00:40:39' scheduledEndTime= 'None' scheduledStartTime= 'None' seasonNumber= '1' seriesID= 'None' seriesInfo= '1/1' serviceType= '0' serviceTypeName= 'Undefined' srsRecordTaskID= 'RT:2902BCCF' subGroupID= '0' title= 'Lost' totalChildSize= '0.0'

EVENT # :2
actualEndTime= '20161121T11:41:00' allowCopyToPlanner= 'True' audioType= '2' audioTypeName= 'Simple stereo' baseType= '3' baseTypeName= 'Download' bookedAsOPPV= 'False' bookingActive= '1' bookingDeletedTime= 'None' bookingDiskQuotaName= 'user' bookingExpirationTime= '19700101T01:00:00' bookingKeep= 'False' bookingLock= 'False' bookingSource= '1' bookingTime= '20161121T11:27:00' bookingType= '4' bookingTypeName= 'Download' boxSetLocator= 'hecid://FFC6AE9C' boxSetName= 'Lost S1' boxSetNameSort= 'Lost S1' boxSetRating= '0' canonicalName= 'Lost' cgmsa= '0' channelID= 'None' channelIDType= 'None' channelName= 'abc studios' channelNr= '0' class= 'object.item.videoItem' cmdcMemberNumber= '2' description= 'Jack tends to a wounded man who reveals a secret about Kate. Contains strong language, violence.(S1, ep 2)' episodeNumber= '2' episodeTitle= 'Pilot (part 2 Of 2) Premiere' estimatedBitRate= '5767168' expireFromPlanner= 'False' extensionStartDur= '0' flagsAllowanalogtaping= 'True' flagsCopyprotected= 'False' flagsCurrentseries= 'False' flagsHasaudiodesc= 'False' flagsHasforeignsubtitles= 'False' flagsHd= 'False' flagsIppv= 'False' flagsIs3D= 'False' flagsIsadult= 'False' flagsIslinked= 'False' flagsOppv= 'False' flagsWidescreen= 'True' genre= '3' genreExtended= '3,772' genreId= 'nds.com_internal' genreName= 'Entertainment' groupID= '0' guardEndDur= 'None' guardStartDur= 'None' isBTO= 'False' isPdlTrailer= '0' isPlaying= 'False' isSeriesLinked= 'False' isShowLinked= '0' isSplitEvent= 'False' isViewed= 'False' itemId= 'BOOK:688045265' itemParentid= '3' itemRestricted= '0' lastPlaybackPosition= '0' lastViewedTime= '19700101T01:00:00' marketingMsg= 'None' oigProgId= '4291228354' parentServiceLocator= 'None' parentalRatingScheme= '1' pdlDownloadStatus= '5' pdlDownloadStatusName= 'ended' pdlPlaybackAvailable= 'True' pdlQueuePosition= '0' pinRating= '4' pinRatingScheme= '1' programID= 'oig://FFC6F2C2' programIDType= 'nds.com_URI' purchaseType= '0' pushExpiryEnd= 'None' pushExpiryStart= 'None' pushHasValidTrailer= 'True' pushLocator= 'None' pushPublishTime= 'None' rating= '0' ratingName= 'Unrated' ratingType= 'nds.com_internal' recStatus= '0' recStatusContentstatus= '3' recStatusContentstatusName= 'All' recStatusException= '100' recStatusFailed= 'False' recStatusName= 'Not applicable' recStatusRecstate= '0' recordedDuration= 'P0D00:38:48' recordedStartDateTime= '20161121T11:35:03' recordingID= 'oig://FFC6F2C2' reminderStatus= '1' reminderStatusIsvcrtimer= 'False' reminderStatusName= 'event is scheduled for a reminder' remoteCDSItemID= 'None' res= 'file://pvr/2902BCD1' resDuration= '0:38:48' resProtocolinfo= 'internal:10.10.8.89:*:*' resSize= '631299676.0' scheduledDuration= 'P0D00:38:48' scheduledEndTime= 'None' scheduledStartTime= 'None' seasonNumber= '1' seriesID= 'None' seriesInfo= '1/2' serviceType= '0' serviceTypeName= 'Undefined' srsRecordTaskID= 'RT:2902BCD1' subGroupID= '0' title= 'Lost' totalChildSize= '0.0'
```

I have got an output.txt file. When user enter the channel number, I would like to delete that whole events.

For example,  if user enters `ChannelNr=102` then if I can fetch `'BOOK:688045263'`
number I will be able to delete event related to channelNr.

I can get the channelNr if its in the file with the following function.

```
def check_channel_number(self):

        print "***************Channel Checker *********************" 

        user_channel_number = int(re.sub('\D', '', raw_input("Enter a channel number, (3digit): "))[:3]);

        self.user_channel_number = user_channel_number

        channel = ("channelNr= '%d'") % (user_channel_number)

        # channel_search = channel + str(user_channel_number)

        datafile = file('output.txt')

        found = False

        for line in datafile:

            if channel in line:
                found = True 
                return user_channel_number

        print 'The channel number you entered is not on the planner'

        return False
```

So, my question is how can get the book number ( itemId= 'BOOK:688045263) on related ChannelNr ?

Comment: Please, format your question. There's so much lost text in it that makes it confusing.

Comment: I tried to reformat your question, please check the result!

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for reformatting my question

Comment: I would use a regex or ``str.split()``...

Answer (score 0):

the first reult in google is https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm, it has some good resources.

string.find() for example will give you the index.

```
str1 = "this is string example....wow!!!";
str2 = "exam";

print str1.find(str2)
15
```

but this is not in regex. does it -have- to be regex?

Could you export this to JSON? That would be a much, much, much cleaner solution and will save you a ton of headache.

you output this text as

`channel = ("channelNr= '%d'") % (user_channel_number)`

You could try

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'channelNr': user_channel_number}, separators=(',', ': '))
```

which will give you

```
{
"channelNr": 602 
}
```

now you can get the data back with

```
jsonData = {    "channelNr": 602     }
dictionary = json.loads(jsonData)[0]
channelNr = dictionary['channelNr']
```

and search it

```
return(channelNr  == 602)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I am already getting the channelNr. My question was that how I can get the BOOK ids, so I can delete the events.

The events is exported in output.txt file.

```
 def check_channel_number(self):

    print "***************Channel Checker *********************" 

    user_channel_number = int(re.sub('\D', '', raw_input("Enter a channel number, (3digit): "))[:3]);

    self.user_channel_number = user_channel_number

    channel = ("channelNr= '%d'") % (user_channel_number)


    # book = ("BOOK: '%d") % ()

    datafile = file('output.txt')

    found = False

    for line in datafile:

        if channel in line:
            found = True 
            return user_channel_number

        print 'The channel number you entered is not on the planner'
        break        



def delete_events(self):


    self.ucn = self.user_channel_number

    are_you_sure = raw_input('Channel number is correct. Are you sure to delete channel number? (y/n): ') 

    if are_you_sure == 'y' and self.ucn >0 :

        print 'The selected program will be deleted'

        action = 'DeleteEvent'
        menu_action = 'all'
        book = 'BOOK:688045265'
        arg_list = [('C:\\Users\\yke01\\Documents\\StormTest\\Scripts\\Completed'
                        '\\Utils\\UPNP_Client_Cmd_Line.py')]
        arg_list.append(' --action=')
        arg_list.append(action)
        arg_list.append(' --ip=')
        arg_list.append('10.10.8.89')
        arg_list.append(' --objectId=')
        arg_list.append(book)

        subprocess.call(["python", arg_list])

        print 'The program deleted successfully'
    else: 
        print 'The program is NOT deleted!'
```

As you can see the book variable is hard coded in delete_events() function. I am trying to to find a way to pass trough book ids (9 digits) dynamically.